# Deleted items are still showing up in the Site Contents section

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, site-contents

I noticed a problem with a Survey list. After all items have been deleted (around 60), there is still a message that 10 were left, but I can't see them:
[image: Site contents]
When I open the list, there are no responses:
[image: List view]

Have any of you experienced this kind of error?

Thanks!
Artur

Comment: If you need to use it again, save it as a list template without content. Or recreate it from a template without content.

Comment: There are certain policies in the organization and we can't do that this way.

Answer (score 1):

Check if these items have unique permissions. Ensure the current user has access on all items in this survey list.

Survey Settings > Permissions for this survey

And navigate to Advanced settings, ensure that user can view others' responses.

[image]

If the current user has not permission to view the responses, he will not view these responses in the survey list and "**Number of Responses**" will not count these responses for him.

Comment: I already checked this option. The number of responses on the list is still 0 and under Site Contents is 10.
On the other hand, my user has full control over the whole web app, so there should be no problem with viewing hidden items, right?

Comment: login as a site collection administrator, and check the list.